# How to disable Crtl + Click

Tags: shortcut

I just switched over to MacOs and it is great until this time.
But there is one big annoyance that I have, when pressing Control and clicking it registers as a right click, can I disable that? so that control + click does nothing in special

Comment: I’m not trying to be flippant here, but why not just *not* press the `Ctrl` key?  Is there a deeper issue you’re trying to solve?

Comment: In games I want to sprint with crtl and do a left click, but it makes it a left click

Comment: What sort of games? If this is a full-screen game without a mouse pointer, then that shouldn't normally be an issue.

Comment: for example minecraft, sprinting and wanting to hit mobs. That is where i have the issue